# IF Statement on Excel/Google Sheets

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets

I'm trying to find a formula in which K4 returns completely blank when J4 is empty. As you can see in the image, it's returning £0.00, but I need it to be blank?

[image: See Formula in Image Below]

Comment: Looks as if either answer will work, but do you have other formatting applied to k4...

Comment: Also, you are testing for a space value it looks like. In excel, this would not return blank due to the presence of `Char(32)`. Are you sure you have the correct test in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how you do it in Google Sheets:

```
=IF(LEN(J4), IF(J4="Won", H4*I4, 0)+IF(J4="Lost", 0, 0), )
```

and whole your formula can be shortened to:

```
=IF(LEN(J4), IF(J4="Won", H4*I4, 0), )
```

Answer (score 0):

### If you want to return a true blank, just skip the return argument

For instance

```
IF(J4 = " ",)
```

---

If this does not work due to formatting disagreements with the above equation, you can return a blank with the below as well

```
IF(J4 = " ", IFERROR(0/0))
```

Comment: Nice, I learned something new today. Didn't realise omitting arguments would return a true blank.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I don't think you can enter a formula and get a completely blank return value.

The next best thing you can do is return a zero-length string `""` -- which isn't the same as a blank cell but might work for you nonetheless.

Maybe you can nest your formula in `=IF(ISBLANK(K4),"",<put the rest of your formula here>)`.